# c++ program core dump when redirecting input stream to string

Tags: rhel, c++

I have recently discovered my c++ program is core dumping on Red Hat Linux when attempting to redirect from an input stream to a string. The program is provided a PID and attempts to obtain the process name from within /proc. Code is as follows:

```
std::string processName;
std::stringstream filename;

filename << "/proc/" << pid << "/status";
std::ifstream f(filename.str().c_str());

if (f.good()) {
  std::string label;
  f >> label; // This causes the core dump

  if (label == "Name:") {
    f >> processName;
  }
}
f.close();
```

I've done some searching and discovered the following c++ bug which looks to be very similar to my issue (note the last comment which is specifically the operation I am performing).
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53984

I have been able to reproduce the problem using a small test program performing the same operation within a tight loop, but still don't quite understand the reasoning behind the actual problem.

Is anyone aware of any problems with attempting to read process names using the method shown above (from within /proc)? I am contemplating rewriting my code to use system calls instead of reading from the file system, but was hoping for some advice prior to making the change.

Comment: This appears to be more a programming question - Stack Overflow might be a better fit.

Comment: Please (re-)read the the [help→tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), especially the part about this being a Q&A site without chit-chat. The "Update' immediately identifies your post as an attempt to abuse this site as a forum, instead of providing, just, a (polished) question. Your comments about leaving this open, should be that, comments. And Thanks are always inappropriate. The more irrelevant material in your Q, the harder it is to follow.

Comment: Updated the post accordingly. 

I have modified my code to make use of system calls to obtain the initial information I was after (process name). I suspect I will be able to perform similar operations to get other required information from /proc/<PID>/stat without relying on reading from the file system.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which can reproduce your problem:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (!pid) {
                // Child process immediately dies and becomes a zombie
                exit(0);
        }

        std::string processName;
        std::stringstream filename;

        // Open status of child process dying
        filename << "/proc/" << pid << "/status";
        std::ifstream f(filename.str().c_str());

        // Wait for child process attaining death
        wait(NULL);

        // Read status of child process already gone
        if (f.good()) {
                std::string label;
                // This causes the core dump
                // read() returns ESRCH (No such process)
                f >> label;

                if (label == "Name:") {
                        f >> processName;
                }
                std::cout << processName << std::endl;
        }
        f.close();

        return 0;
}
```

And `strace -f ./a.out` shows:

```
clone(Process 624 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f20758daa10) = 624
[pid   623] brk(0)                      = 0x8b8000
[pid   623] brk(0x8d9000)               = 0x8d9000
[pid   623] open("/proc/624/status", O_RDONLY <unfinished ...>
[pid   624] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid   623] <... open resumed> )        = 3
[pid   623] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[pid   624] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> NULL, 0, NULL)      = 624
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=624, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
read(3, 0x8b84b0, 8191)                 = -1 ESRCH (No such process)
write(2, "terminate called after throwing "..., 48terminate called after throwing an instance of ') = 48
write(2, "std::ios_base::failure", 22std::ios_base::failure)  = 22
write(2, "'\n", 2'
)                      = 2
write(2, "  what():  ", 11  what():  )             = 11
write(2, "basic_filebuf::underflow error r"..., 47basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file) = 47
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [ABRT], NULL, 8) = 0
gettid()                                = 623
tgkill(623, 623, SIGABRT)               = 0
--- SIGABRT {si_signo=SIGABRT, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=623, si_uid=1000} ---
+++ killed by SIGABRT (core dumped) +++
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The root cause would be that kernel returns `ESRCH` (No such process) on `read()` which is unexpected by libstdc++.  I'm not sure which to blame here, kernel or userland library.